# String Concatenation Issue

Tags: perl, string

Could you please have a look at my code below.

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe 
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use Data::Dumper;  

my $fh = \*DATA;  
my $str1 = "listBox1.Items.Add(\"";
my $str2 = "\")\;";

while(my $line = <$fh>)
{
    $line=~s/^\s+//g;

    print $str1.$line.$str2;

    chomp($line);

}


__DATA__  
Hello
 World
```

Output:

```
D:\learning\perl>test.pl
listBox1.Items.Add("Hello
");listBox1.Items.Add("World
");
D:\learning\perl>
```

Style error. I want the style below. Is ther anything wrong about my code? thanks.

```
D:\learning\perl>test.pl
listBox1.Items.Add("Hello");
listBox1.Items.Add("World");
D:\learning\perl>
```

Comment: And the database connection is where exactly?!

Comment: @Paulo, I modified the tag from **connection-string** to **string**. :-)

Comment: Title edited for "connection"->"concatenation" as well.

Comment: This is not related to your main question, but remember that `print` is like many Perl functions. It takes a **list** of arguments. Rather than concatenating several arguments and then passing 1 argument to `print`, simply pass them directly. Like this: `print $str1, $line, $str2, "\n"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line read in `$line` has a trailing `newline` char. You need to use `chomp` to get rid of it. You have chomp in your code, but its misplaced. Move it to the start of the loop as:

```
while(my $line = <$fh>)
{
    chomp($line);                 # remove the trailing newline.
    $line=~s/^\s+//g;             # remove the leading white space.
    print $str1.$line.$str2."\n"; # append a newline at the end.
}
```

**EDIT:**

Answer to the question in the comment:

To remove the ***leading*** whitespace in a string:

```
$str =~s/^\s+//;
```

To remove the ***trailing(ending)*** whitespace in a string:

```
$str =~s/\s+$//;
```

To remove the ***leading and trailing*** whitespace in a string:

```
$str =~s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
```

Comment: I think the problem is on the regular expression that's selecting the new line character. Take a look at the desired response.

Comment: @unicornaddict
Thank you again. Acturally I am developing a C# application, BTW, I want to simplify my C# code with the aid of Perl. :-)

Comment: @unicornaddict: How to remove the ending white space?  Then I can handle the ending white space like this, ***listBox1.Items.Add("Hello   ");*** thank you.

Comment: Not quite there with the last one. You'll need `s/^\s+|\s+$//g` to ensure that leading **and** trailing spaces are removed

Answer (score 2):

Think about the order, between print and chomp ;)